# Не получается обновить событие созданное с помощью библиотеки BiWeekly и посланное с Java Mail API

Tags: csv, calendar, outlook, javamail, google-calendar

Мне нужно послать приглашение на какое то событие, а затем обновить его. Чтобы создать событие (**VEVENT**) я использую библиотеку [BiWeekly](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biweekly/), а затем посылаю его с помощью [Java Mail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Создать событие получается без проблем и когда клиент (Lotus Notes, GMail) получает email он без проблем создает событие в календаре. Проблема возникла в том случае если я хочу изменить это событие. Когда я посылаю новый email с изменениями то клиент всегда создает новое событие. `UID` в обеих email одинаковый, `SEQUENCE` *0* и *1* соответственно. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Код который я использую:

```
try {
    String from = "email@example.com";
    String to = "email@example.com";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    prop.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.example.com");
    prop.setProperty("mail.user", "email");
    prop.setProperty("mail.password", "");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);

    // Define message
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
    message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
    message.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT");

    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject("Message Subject");

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();


    /*EVENT START*/
    VEvent event = new VEvent();
    event.setUid("ANATOLYTARNAVSKY123");
    event.setDescription("Invitation Description");
    event.setSummary("Invitation Description");
    event.setOrganizer("anatolyt@gmail.com");
    event.setLocation("room");

    event.setSequence(sequence);


    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sequence + 2);
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sequence + 2);

    event.setDateStart(start.getTime());
    event.setDateEnd(end.getTime());
    icals.addEvent(event);

    WriterChainText text = Biweekly.write(icals);
    String result = text.go(); 


    System.out.println(result);
    /*EVENT END*/

    StringBuffer buffer = sb.append(result);


    // Create the message part
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    // Fill the message
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler( new ByteArrayDataSource(buffer.toString(), "text/calendar")));// very important

    // Create a Multipart
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // Add part one
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // Put parts in message
    message.setContent(multipart);

    // send message
    Transport.send(message);
} catch (MessagingException me) {
    me.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Вот `VEVENT` которые генерируются `BiWeekly`:

Создание:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Michael Angstadt//biweekly 0.4.3//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20151113T100301Z
UID:ANATOLYTARNAVSKY123
DESCRIPTION:Invitation Description
SUMMARY:Invitation Description
ORGANIZER:mailto:anatolyt@il.ibm.com
LOCATION:room
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTART:20151113T120301Z
DTEND:20151113T120301Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Изменение:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Michael Angstadt//biweekly 0.4.3//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20151113T100333Z
UID:ANATOLYTARNAVSKY123
DESCRIPTION:Invitation Description
SUMMARY:Invitation Description
ORGANIZER:mailto:anatolyt@il.ibm.com
LOCATION:room
SEQUENCE:1
DTSTART:20151113T130333Z
DTEND:20151113T130333Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Спасибо за любую помощь.